# How modify to PHP SQL SELECT query to display message depending on if data is found

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following SELECT query that shows data depending on if it exists in the mySQL table.

Right now if it does it will display all of the records found, If not it will just display nothing.

**I would like to make it display if the record is found**

```
{"error":false}
```

**and If the record is not found**

```
{"error":true}
```

The following is what I have so far:

```
$sql =  "SELECT field1,field2
        from Table1 WHERE field3 = 'Dog' ";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // Create temporary connection
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Look through each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize an array with a default value, then change the value if the records are found

```
$sql =  "SELECT field1,field2
        from Table1 WHERE field3 = 'Dog' ";

$resultArray = ['error' => true];

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // Create temporary connection
    $tempArray = array();

    // Look through each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    $resultArray['error'] = false;
}

echo json_encode($resultArray);

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
$return = [
    'error' => true
];
$sql =  "SELECT field1,field2
        from Table1 WHERE field3 = 'Dog' ";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if($result && $result->num_rows > 0){
    $return['error'] = false;
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($return);
```